# How to databind a gridview from an other aspx file that is opened as a pop up window in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

My problem is the following. I have an aspx webform(ErrorList.aspx). This webform has a gridview control and a sqldatasource control. The sqldatasource control has the select statement from the table and the gridview displays the result. The last column contains an imagebutton. Imagebutton's code has this :
OnClientClick="addFileWindow(this);"
You can see there is an onclientclick part and a javascript function is called here. Function's code is here :

```
function addFileWindow(ib) {

            var id = ib;
            var azon = id.title;

            $("#Azon_row_lbl").hide();
            $("#Azon_row_lbl").text(azon);

            window.open("addNewFile.aspx", "", "scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600, height=300");

            return false;
        }
```

So if you click on the imagebutton a pop up window will be opened. 
It contains a fileupload manager control and an upload button and an error label. Error label will be displayed if there is no selected file. Error label will be on hide status if there is a selected file. If everything is alright and there is a selected file the program will update the database cell with the name of the file and the file will be uploaded to the server into the uploaded files folder in the project. Its working. So this is not problem for me. Here is the code of the addNewFile.aspx:
Client side :

```
<title>File upload</title>


<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {

            var parent = $(window.opener.document).contents();
            $("#myDiv1").html("<u>Here is the ID of the record of the new file: </u>");
            $("#myDiv2").html(parent.find("#Azon_row_lbl").html());

        }
    });
</script>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="myDiv1" runat="server" style="color: white;"></div>
    <div id="myDiv2" runat="server" style="color: white;"></div>

    <asp:Label ID="lbl_id" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br /><br />

    <asp:FileUpload ID="fu_ter_ell_update_attch" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>

    <br /><br />

    <asp:Button ID="Upload_file_bttn" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload_file_bttn_Click" Height="33px" style="font-weight: 700; color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #000000;" Width="77px" />

    <br /><br />

    <asp:Label ID="Error_label" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="There is no selected file!" style="font-weight: 700; color: #FF0000"></asp:Label>

</form>


 <script type="text/javascript">

     $("#<%= Upload_file_bttn.ClientID %>").click(function () {


         var ID = $('#myDiv2').text();
         var filename = $('#<%= fu_ter_ell_update_attch.ClientID %>').val();


         if (filename != "")
         {
             var res = filename.split("\\");
             //   res[res.length-1]   this reference contains the name of the file . extension for example apple.jpg
             var file_exist = "";

             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 url: 'addNewFile.aspx/DataBase_Has_This_FileName_Or_Not',
                 data: "{'FileName':'" + res[res.length - 1] + "'}",
                 async: false,
                 success: function (response) {
                     file_exist = response.d;
                 },
                 error: function () {
                     alert("Error");
                     return false;
                 }
             });

             if (file_exist == true)
             {
                 alert("Database has this filename already. Change it and try to upload again.");
                 return false;
             }
             else
             {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     url: 'addNewFile.aspx/Attach_FileName_Into_Row',
                     data: "{'ID':'" + ID + "','FileName':'" + res[res.length - 1] + "'}",
                     async: false,
                     success: function (response) {

                     },
                     error: function () {
                         alert("Error");
                         return false;
                     }
                 });
             }

         }

     });

</script>
```

Server side :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}


[WebMethod]
public static bool DataBase_Has_This_FileName_Or_Not(string FileName)
{
    bool retvalue = false;

    string selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM [DNTShiftReport].[dbo].[ter_ell_hiany_DNT] WHERE [Filename] = @Filename";

    string connectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DNTShiftReportConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, conn))
        {
            try
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add("@Filename", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FileName;

                conn.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        retvalue = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message); }
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
        }
    }

    return retvalue;
}


[WebMethod]
public static void Attach_FileName_Into_Row(string ID, string FileName)
{
    string connectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DNTShiftReportConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand comm = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            comm.CommandText = "UPDATE [ter_ell_hiany_DNT] SET [Filename] = @filename WHERE [ID] = @upd_id";
            comm.Parameters.Add("@filename", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FileName;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@upd_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}


protected void Upload_file_bttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (fu_ter_ell_update_attch.HasFile)
    {

        Error_label.Visible = false;


        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fu_ter_ell_update_attch.FileName);
        string saveDir = @"\DNTShiftReport\Uploaded_files\";
        string appPath = Server.MapPath(saveDir);
        string fullpath = appPath + filename;
        fu_ter_ell_update_attch.SaveAs(fullpath);


        Session["POP_UP_CLOSED"] = "CLOSED";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.open('close.html', '_self', null);", true); // close the pop up window.

    }
    else
    {
        Error_label.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

So my problem is that, database is updated, file is uploaded, but the gridview should be databinded automatically when the pop up window is closed by the button. I cant databind the gridview on the addNewFile.aspx because the gridview's location is the ErrorList.aspx. I tried every solution that I find in the google in the last 3 days but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely client side problem. Possible solution:

Instead of

```
window.open("addNewFile.aspx", "", "scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600, height=300");
```

you can have

```
var addNewFileWindow = window.open("addNewFile.aspx", "", "scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600, height=300");
addNewFileWindow.onBeforeUnload = function(){ 
// handle window closing
// just reload the page
window.location.reload()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to automatically bind the gridview to data when the popup closes. (NOTE: I suggest not to reload page using JavaScript on closing of popup, since then you may receive a browser message asking if you want to post data and this might not be the desired behavior your users would like to see. So, I think the hidden button approach would be the best approach.)

- Add a hidden button to the parent page as in markup below.
- We will programatically click this button when the popup is closed
  using JavaScript and this clicking will automatically post the page
  and fire the button click event on server-side.
- In this server-side click event, we can databind the gridview.

Please change your onclientclick to this: `OnClientClick="return addFileWindow(this);"`, else the button will post back causing undesirable behavior.

**Hidden button on parent page**

```
<div style="display: none">
    <asp:Button ID="btnPost" runat="server" Text="Post" OnClick="btnPost_Click" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript on parent page for subscribing to close event of popup**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var wnd = null;

function onPopupClosing() {
            var hiddenButton = wnd.opener.document.getElementById("<%=btnPost.ClientID%>");
            if (hiddenButton) {
                hiddenButton.click();
            }
        }
function addFileWindow(ib) {

            var id = ib;
            var azon = id.title;

            $("#Azon_row_lbl").hide();
            $("#Azon_row_lbl").text(azon);

            //get center coordinates for popup
            var x = screen.width / 2 - 600 / 2;
            var y = screen.height / 2 - 300 / 2;
            //open popup
            wnd = window.open("addNewFile.aspx", "", "scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600, height=300, left="+ x + ", top="+ y);
            wnd.onbeforeunload = onPopupClosing;
            wnd.focus();
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

**Code-behind for databinding gridview  when popup closes**

```
protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //bind the grid view
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

NOTE: If you are using UpdatePanel i.e. your gridview is within an UpdatePanel. If yes, then you need to make sure that the settings on UpdatePanel are as given in below markup and also the hidden button is within the UpdatePanel. The property settings `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"`  and `UpdateMode="Always"` are important else this may not work.

**When UpdatePanel is used**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AllowPaging="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityPerUnit" HeaderText="QuantityPerUnit" SortExpression="QuantityPerUnit" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="UnitPrice" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsInStock" HeaderText="UnitsInStock" SortExpression="UnitsInStock" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsOnOrder" HeaderText="UnitsOnOrder" SortExpression="UnitsOnOrder" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Discontinued" HeaderText="Discontinued" SortExpression="Discontinued" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CheckBox Column">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Discontinued") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CheckBox Column">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnPopup" runat="server" OnClientClick="return addFileWindow(this)" ImageUrl="~/images/logo.png" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
           </asp:GridView>
        <div style="display: none;">
            <asp:Button ID="btnPost" runat="server" Text="Post" OnClick="btnPost_Click" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but you know the addFileWindow function is fired when I click the imagebutton in the end of the gridview's row so your code is fired when I open the pop up window. Databind is working but not in the good time. I have to databind the grid on the parent aspx file when I close the pop up window. Can I get more help? I  tried to combinate these two solution here but unfortunatelly it is still not good.

Comment: Sorry.  I may have pasted wrong code.  I will paste the correct code in a few minutes.

Comment: @lace789, Please try now. I have pasted the correct code.

Comment: I tried it but still doesnt work. You called the onbeforeunload inside the addFileWindow function. The Problem is that the addFileWindow is calling only one time when I click the imagebutton inside the gridview's itemtemplate field and open the pop up window. So that part would work probably but never will be called in this case.  <asp:ImageButton ID="ib_new_attach" runat="server" Height="40px" Width="40px" OnClientClick="return addFileWindow(this);" ToolTip='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ImageUrl="img/Buttons/Upload_icon.png"/>

Comment: What button when clicked opens the popup in your page?

Comment: Note that `wnd` is defined as a global variable and so when its event for `onbeforeunload` is set, then it will always be called the popup i.e. wnd is closing. It will always be called if the image button you are clicking calls the function`addFileWindow`. The only thing I may have omitted is to set `wnd = null;` at start of `addFileWindow` function, so old popup does not interfere with new popup.

Comment: You can see this video, https://drive.google.com/file/d/152Y50G7FUkT2eENk5IZl9Ysiw3USdakw/view,  where you will notice that the hidden button server-side click event is always firing when popup is closed. I am not sure if your situation is different from this. If yes, then let me know.

Comment: Hi im here. Yesterday I was on an Excel training, out of office. So Day before yesterday before I went home I tried this that I see in this video and I realised that I will be mad soon. I opened pop ups and closed 8 times. And its worked but not every time only 2 times. There is no logic in it. My grid is in a updatepanel. Can it be the problem ? Today I will add a new form and I will compare what you send me by this video and my solution.

Comment: Please paste the markup in your question i..e. html of gridview and update panel. There could be some change needed if you use update panel, but it would depend on your update panel configuration.

Comment: I have posted how UpdatePanel scenario can be handled. Also, I have taken the onbeforeunload anonymous function out of the addFileWindow function, which could be easier to read and debug.

Comment: Still doesnt work. Yesterday I created a test2.aspx file and wrote a very simple example without updatepanel. And this is not working too. Can I send you this source code? Can I get an email adress?  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Did you follow the exact logic I explained in my answer?  Can you join the chat  at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159450/lace789issue

Comment: Sure I did. I tried to use the chat but I got this message : You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq. So here is my email adress : lacicelica@gmail.com please write me there and I send you everything